# Github Actions, permission denied when using custom shell

Tags: permissions, github-actions

I am trying to use a shell script as a [custom shell](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#custom-shell) in Github Actions like this:

```
- name: Test bash-wrapper
  shell: bash-wrapper {0}
  run: |
    echo Hello world
```

However, when I try to run it, I get Permission denied.

Background: I have set up a chroot jail, which I use with QEMU user mode emulation in order to build for non-IA64 architectures with toolchains that lack cross-compilation support.

The script is intended to provide a bash shell on the target architecture and looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo chroot --userspec=`whoami`:`whoami` $CROSS_ROOT qemu-arm-static /bin/bash -c "$*"
```

It resides in `/bin/bash-wrapper` and it thus on `$PATH`.

Digging a bit deeper, I found:

- Running `bash-wrapper "echo Hello world"` in a GHA step with the default shell works as expected.
- Running `bash-wrapper 'echo Running as $(whoami)'` from the default shell correctly reports we are running as user `runner`.
- Removing `--userspec` from the `chroot` command in `bash-wrapper` (thus running the command as root) does not make a difference – the custom shell gives the same error.
- GHA converts each step into a script file and passes it to the shell.
- File ownership on these files is `runner:docker`, `runner` being the user that runs the job by default.
- Interestingly, the script files generated by GHA are not executable. I suspect that is what is ultimately causing the permission error.
- Indeed, if I modify `bash-wrapper` to set the executable bit on the script before running it, everything works as expected.

I imagine non-executable script files would cause all sorts of troubles with various shells, thus I would expect GHA would have a way of dealing with that – in fact I am a bit surprised these on-the-fly scripts are not executable by default.

Is there a less hacky way of fixing this, such as telling GHA to set the executable bit on temporary scripts? (How does Github expect this to be solved?)

Answer (score 4):

When calling your script try running it like this:

```
- name: Test bash-wrapper
  shell: bash-wrapper {0}
  run: |
     bash <your_script>.sh
```

Alternatively, try running this command locally and the commit and push the repository:

```
git update-index --chmod=+x <your_script>.sh
```

Comment: The script is not something from my repo, but a script created dynamically by GHA, using the commands in `run`. It resides in some temp dir within `~runner`, and the file name is a GUID, potentially with a `.sh` extension. Your suggestion won’t work for that scenario.

Comment: how do you run the script?

Comment: The `run:` section is a list of shell commands. GHA processes them (resolving CI variables and the like) and saves the result to a temporary script file. This file, however, does not have the executable flag set. I have next to no influence over the creation of this file, but I figure there must be a way to tell GHA to create it with the executable bit set, as a bunch of shells would have issues otherwise.